# I am getting SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) and Email could not been sent. Mailer Error (Line 301): SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, xampp, smtp, codeigniter-3

I am using xampp server .
Using CodeIgniter 3 .

config/email.php file

```
// Add custom values by settings them to the $config array.
// Example: $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
// @link https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

// $config['useragent'] = 'CodeIgniter';
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp'; // or 'smtp'
$config['mailtype'] = 'html'; // or 'text'
$config['smtp_debug'] = '1'; // or '1'
$config['smtp_auth'] = TRUE; //or FALSE for anonymous relay.
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'myemailid@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'mypassword';
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl'; // or 'tls'
$config['smtp_port'] = 587;
```

[image]

Comment: Gmail doesn't allow simple connects with username & password any more. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps

Comment: than what should i do ?

Comment: Either check if you can still enable "less secure apps", https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255 (but AFAIK Google re-sets this periodically), or implement XOAUTH2.

Comment: i have tested a simple php code that send email and it is working fine . I am able to send email through smtp protocol . for that i have changes some things in php.ini file and sendmail.ini file . in xampp server .

Comment: Okay, but then you probably won't actually be sending the mail _via_ Google's servers any more. (Which could affect how likely the receiving servers will be to treat it as spam.)

Comment: whan i send email using simple php file it is not treated as spam . in  receiver's gmail app mail is coming in primary section .

Comment: _"it is not treated as spam"_ - for now. Depending on the amount of mails you will be sending, that could change over time. _"in receiver's gmail app mail is coming in primary section "_ - are you only ever sending to one and the same recipient? If not, this has little validity for how other recipients might react.